# How to import configurable product from CSV using magmi importer

Tags: magento

Magento Magmi importer is able to import the simple product but configurable product are creating as a simple products. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure,

Check [this](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Configurable_Item_processor) out, it may help you to make it right.